# Grails validation not working

Tags: validation, grails, domain-object

I'm trying to do some validation on a domain class object, but I get a strange exception when I call the 'validate' method. I have a form where I input some data:
[image: Html form]
Here is the code for my form:

```
<body>
<div id='register'>
    <div class='inner'>
        <div class='fheader'>Register</div>

        <g:if test='${flash.message}'>
            <div class='login_message'>${flash.message}</div>
        </g:if>

        <form action='<g:createLink controller="register" action="create" />' method='POST' id='registerForm' class='cssform' autocomplete='off'>
            <p>
                <label for='username'>Username:</label>
                <input type='text' class='text_' name='username' id='username'/>
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for='password'>Password:</label>
                <input type='password' class='text_' name='password' id='password'/>
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for='passwordConfirmation'>Confirm:</label>
                <input type='password' class='text_' name='passwordConfirm' id='passwordConfirmation'/>
            </p>

            <p>
                <input type='submit' id="submit" value='REGISTER'/>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is the code for my controller. The method that recieves the POST is 'create'.

```
package genealogicaltree

import gentree.security.UserCommand
import grails.converters.JSON
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured

@Secured('permitAll')
class RegisterController {

    static allowedMethods = [index:'GET', create:['POST']]

    def springSecurityService

    def index() {
       render(view: 'register')
    }

    def create() {
        def userCommand = new UserCommand(params)
        if(userCommand.validate())
            render "valid"
        else
            render "invalid"
    }
}
```

Here is how my domain class looks like:

```
class UserCommand{
    public String username 
    public String password
    public String passwordConfirm
    static constraints = {
        username  size: 6..15, blank: false
        password  size: 6..15, blank: false
        passwordConfirm blank: false
    }
}
```

Using debugging I can see that the data from POST is binded to the userCommand object : 
[image]

However, I get such an error message:
[image]

Here is the console output:

```
Error |
2015-04-02 15:41:57,180 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NotReadablePropertyException occurred when processing request: [POST] /GenealogicalTree/register/create - parameters:
passwordConfirm: password
username: username
password: ***
Invalid property 'username' of bean class [gentree.security.UserCommand]: Bean property 'username' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Invalid property 'username' of bean class [gentree.security.UserCommand]: Bean property 'username' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    Line | Method
->>   20 | create    in genealogicaltree.RegisterController
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     49 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|     82 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

The exception is thrown when the code calls 'userCommand.validate()'. I don't understand what am I doing wrong here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding getters and setters?

Comment: It works. Shouldn't Grails generate these methods by default? If I remeber correctly, I could call setters and getters methods for objects of domain classes without having to write the methods. I'm still learning Grails and I make silly mistakes from time to time. Post your answer so I can mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Which version of Grails are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add getters and setters into your domain class to remove this.

The Grails compiler will generate these methods by default, so for example.

```
myObject.myValue = "hello";
```

is the same as

```
myObject.setMyValue("hello");
```

However, it is obviously not perfect and you get errors like this! If you're using Grails version < 2.3.2, then this is a known bug and there is a [Jira Issue](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10664) for it, so you can solve it by upgrading your version of Grails.

Comment: The thing is I'm using Grails 2.4.4. It's a little bit strange, but it worked, so i'm happy.

Comment: Well.. yes that is strange. Perhaps you should comment on the issue!